# ASP.Net membership provider with 1 database and multiple web servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I will be launching an mvc3 project soon.  The project will be run on multiple servers which all point to the same database.  The project uses ASP.Net's membership provider.  I need to ensure that a user created on Server 1 will be able to login to Server 2.

Question:  Will there be any issues with automatically generated enryption/decryption keys that the membership provider uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the `MembershipProvider` (we derive our own version of it) for a load-balanced application and I haven't had an issue with it.

As for the default `SqlMembershipProvider`, if you're either hashing your passwords or storing them in clear text, you should be fine.  If you're encrypting them, just make sure that your web servers all have the same key values in the machine.config's `<machineKey>` configuration section.  See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating an active directory role and then give the role access to the web site. Embed a proxy username and password for the database in the web.config file. The web.config file is not visible to any users and it can be encrypted.